Difference between perfect + infinitive vs perfect + perfect infinitive
I'm working on a text and had this doubt about past tense. I want to say 'I liked seeing you' but I'm not sure if there's a difference between amavi videre te and amavi vidisse te.
Litterally I translated them as I liked seeing you and I liked having seen you whose difference I make in that 'having seen you' is a one-time event and 'seeing you' is an indefinite amount of time, but I don't know that in latin they'd be interpreted the same way.

amo + infinitive is possible but relatively rare. I don't think it's the best way to translate the English idiom, "I like doing X." I would probably use something with the verb placet or the adverb libenter.
